# Android bug: WebViewCore fails with Assertion error

Tags: android

Unfortunately I cannot reliably reproduce this error but infrequently I get it and occasionally it gets reported in the live crash logs also. Here's a stacktrace reported by user with `Droid 2.2.2 FRG83G`

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:233)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:226)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:594)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

This seems to be due to this line in `WebViewCore.java`

```
Assert.assertNull(sWebCoreHandler);
```

Somehow sWebCoreHandler which is private static instance of `android.os.Handler` is <strike>not</strike> *(Thanks @Idolon for the correction)* **already** initialized but I have no clue how to work around or prevent this issue.

This occurs often enough for me to worry. What is also interesting is seemingly happens when the app is loading `Activity` that doesn't even have WebView though one of the activities does have it.

P.S. This was filed as bug #[16258](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16258)

Comment: so? what do you want exactly? Can you tell us if there is something "special" in your webview?

Comment: I want someone to explain me what's the problem and how to avoid/fix it. There's nothing special in "my" webview and I can't reproduce this bug when I run the code yet my ACRA logs are full of it. And this is complete stack-trace

Comment: Do you have any clue what line in your code is causing the problem? If you are the only one who has reported this bug in 6 months it could be a bug in your code.

Comment: `Somehow sWebCoreHandler … is not initialized` - not correct. If `Assert.assertNull(sWebCoreHandler)` throws an exception this means that `sWebCoreHandler` was *NOT* null (i.e. it has been already initialized by the another thread).

Comment: @Idolon that's a very valid point, it just could be the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the incriminating source code...

```
public WebViewCore(Context context, WebView w, CallbackProxy proxy,
        Map<String, Object> javascriptInterfaces) {

    //....

    // We need to wait for the initial thread creation before sending
    // a message to the WebCore thread.
    // XXX: This is the only time the UI thread will wait for the WebCore
    // thread!
    synchronized (WebViewCore.class) {
        if (sWebCoreHandler == null) {
            // Create a global thread and start it.
            Thread t = new Thread(new WebCoreThread());

            //...

        }
    }

//...

private static Handler sWebCoreHandler;
// Class for providing Handler creation inside the WebCore thread.
private static class WebCoreThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        Assert.assertNull(sWebCoreHandler); // this assertion fails
        synchronized (WebViewCore.class) {
            sWebCoreHandler = new Handler() {
        //...
```

This is executed in the constructor of any `WebView` and the assertion error comes from the `WebCoreThread` constructor, which is only called when the `sWebCoreHandler` is null, so this assertion should never fail... in theory. Except it's ran outside of the synchronized clause and inside a new Thread that is created and started inside a synchronized clause, supposedly only once.

It seems your error is tied to concurrent creation of webviews. If your application has only one activity with one webview, make sure that this activity is not called more often than necessary (=one at a time), that the WebView is created in the onCreate method rather than the activity constructor, that the startActivity is called in the main thread, and you should be good.

Comment: These are good, valid points, but as it is - there is just one WebView in my code that is initialized in onCreate method of activity. I wonder if this has to do with stoping/restarting or pausing/activating the activity and somehow losing the static singleton in the process??

Comment: OMG… Such a naive synchronization. If someone tries to create 2 `WebView` from different threads it could lead to an Assertion error. They should really use ["Initialization on demand holder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) idiom for `sWebCoreHandler` (and "WebCoreThread" as well) static singleton initialization.

Comment: @DroidIn.net : I'm not really sure, maybe it has to do with memory management, maybe your activity is destroyed and recreated in two different threads. You filed a bug to Google, right? So somewhere down the road it should be fixed. In the mean time, I'm not sure if this assertion failure kills the VM - I mean, as long as the static Handler is not null, your app should run fine, right?

Comment: @ThomasPhilipakis the problem is that even if google fixes this "way down the road", we'll still have millions of users with an old android SDK.

Comment: @DroidIn.net: bare in mind that 95% of the ad network SDK's are implemented using webview's. Please verify if you have one of those before or after your activity is started. Maybe it could happen that you're in one activity, that has an ad, and then the user click to open a new activity, that also has an webview, and then in the meantime the ad has been populated and its webview have been initialized.